# Google Apps Script executes but won't send requests to SMS service

Tags: google-apps-script, sms-gateway

Wrote GA script to auto-send messages through 46Elks: it was working for a couple of days, but now the script executes yet doesn't actually send the requests out. Why would it suddenly stop working?

Below is the part of the script that sends the messages to 46Elks:

```
...
// Loop over all rows in the range and send the SMS to 46Elks
for (var i in range) {
  if (range[i][1] == '' || range[i][3] == 'SENT') continue;
  var state = sheet.getRange(2+Number(i), 4);
  var info = sheet.getRange(2+Number(i), 5);
  try {
    UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.46elks.com/a1/SMS", {
      "method": "post",
      "headers": { "Authorization": "Basic " + auth },
      "payload": {
        "from" : sender,
        "to" : '+' + range[i][1],
        "message" : range[i][2]
      }
    });
    state.setValue('SENT').setBackground('#93c47d');
    info.setValue('Sent on ' + new Date());
  } catch (err) {
    state.setValue('FAILED').setBackground('#e06666');
    info.setValue(String(err).replace('\n', ''));
  }
}
...
```

I set up Head time-driven triggers to auto-execute the script every day, and the log shows that all executions were successful. However, the 46Elks dashboard shows no requests came through since I set up the triggers. Haven't made any changes to the code, it just stopped working.

Comment: Did you try reaching help@46elks.com?